# Как выключить виртуальное окружение (venv) в терминале VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, venv

Подскажите как выключить виртуальное окружение (venv) в терминале VSCode? Пробовал комаду deactivate - не работает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]